# Cannot instantiate service although it is loaded

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

This is the main module:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module('wda', [
            /* Angular modules */
            'ngRoute',

            /* 3rd-party modules */
            'ui.bootstrap',

            /* Feature areas */
            'wda.overview',

            /* Shared resources */ 
            'websiteService'
        ])
        .config(function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/overview'
                });
        });

}());
```

This is a service I'd like to use throughout the app:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module('wda')
        .factory('websiteService', websiteService);

    websiteService.$inject = ['$window', '$q'];

    function websiteService($window, $q) {
        var svc = {};

        return svc;
    }

}());
```

This is how I load them in index.html, just above the `</body>` tag:

```
<script src="scripts/vendor/angular.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/vendor/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/vendor/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.module.js"></script>
<script src="app/overview/overview.module.js"></script>
<script src="app/overview/overview.controller.js"></script>
<script src="app/shared/website-service/websiteService.service.js"></script>
```

All the files get loaded, there's no 404's, but still I get this error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module wda
>   due to: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   websiteService due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module
>   'websiteService' is not available! You either misspelled the module
>   name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you
>   specify the dependencies as the second argument.

I understand what it says, but don't understand why it happens. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: I may be wrong, but if you've created your service in a closure, will it even be visible / accessible?

Comment: Why are you trying to add websiteService as a dependant module? It's currently in wad module so there is no need to add /* Shared resources */'websiteService'

Comment: @jonnyknowsbest Removed the closure, still getting the same error.

Comment: @WayneEllery I'm trying to keep each component in a separate file, as per this guide: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#folders-by-feature-structure     Maybe I'm misunderstanding how to do this?

Comment: Yes, that's fine, but each doesn't need to be in a separate module. Take a look at the answer below. Once you have a factory, to use it all you need to do is add it to the constructor of your controller. There is no need to add websiteService to the main module

Comment: But I want to use websiteService in most controllers of the app, not just that one. Does it make sense then to make it part of the main module? As for the answer below (again, if I'm not misunderstanding), I'm trying to stick to the guidelines, this part specifically: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y091

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare your service like this:

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('wda')
       .factory('websiteService', ['$window','$q',function($window,$q){
            
           var svc = {};
         
           return svc;
         
        }]);
```

Then in your controller, you can inject your factory:

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('wda')
       .controller('YourCtrl',['websiteService', function(websiteService){
       
         //Whatever you want to do with your service
       }]);
```